# Add projection warp calculation to preserve correct scale when exporting map for printing

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, distortion

I'm working on my own widget for printing large maps based on the ArcGIS printing service. The main feature of the service will be dividing the large area to separate parts in specified paper format.

Calculations of areas based on the calculation of the distance that fits into one pixel:

Notation that I use:

- DPI - the number of pixels per inch (2.54 cm).
- SCALE - the scale of the result printed map
- MAP_SCALE - the current scale of the user's browser map
- TRUE_SCALE - the real scale of some area on the map with calculated distortion of the Mercator projection
- latitude - the latitude in which the calculations take place
- k - is the number of pixels per scale unit (for me it's always centimeters)
- EXTENT - map printing area.
- HEIGHT - height of the resulting image (for A4 29.7 cm)
- WIDTH - width of the resulting image (for A4 21 cm)

k = (DPI * SCALE) / (2.54 * MAP_SCALE)

So, at a scale of 1:25,000 k is the number of pixels on the map that will correspond to a distance of 250 meters (25,000 cm / 100 cm in a meter).

The problem is that when the latitude in which printing is increased, the scale of the map decreases according to the following formula: TRUE_SCALE = MAP_SCALE * (1 / cos(latitude)

When displaying the map and in the printing service, this fact is not taken into account, therefore, when moving from the equator to the pole, the same number of pixels includes an increasingly smaller distance. This leads to a scale violation when printing the map.

I find two possible solutions for that problem:

1. Reduce DPI according to distortion (pixel size compensation)
2. Increasing the size of the source file according to distortion and downscaling it manually

It is important for me to maintain the quality of the resulting map, so I am looking for alternative solutions.

Also, I found that the original Arcgis-js print widget ([docs here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Print.html)) does not save the correct scale if